# CloudFormation template -> ALB target group not supporting http/TCP protocol

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-application-load-balancer

So i have an entire stack which creates autoscalling, VPC and ELB(classic)
im trying to replace that with an Application load balancer and i have given the template bit below.

so the error im facing is

```
TargetGroup1    CREATE_FAILED

Target type 'alb' is not supported for target groups with HTTP protocol (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidConfigurationRequest; Request ID: 29cdf7fd-5b12-4ef6-b812-baee840038ff; Proxy: null)
```

in 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup' I had changed Protocol: HTTP to Protocol: tcp as seen in console config for type alb

Note: StackALB created, ALBlistener not created yet

```
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer'
    Properties:
      Name: StackALB
      Scheme: internet-facing
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
      Subnets:
        - !Ref PublicSubnet0
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet0
      Type: application
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 421548e4-192c-4a89-b236-41eb956dc7f3
  TargetGroup1:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup'
    Properties:
      TargetType: alb
      Targets:
        - Id: !Ref StackALB
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 3517f34b-2be3-49d1-a3b6-8db672475be2
  ALBlistener:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener'
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          ForwardConfig:
            TargetGroups:
              - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup1
                Weight: 1
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref StackALB
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: d0c17083-9c13-48c2-8e13-948b2a096e71
```

entire template for ref

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Metadata:
  License: Apache-2.0
  'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
    9b07d92a-36f9-4ca7-b4f9-40753f1378b0:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 670
        'y': 270
      z: 2
      parent: 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
      embeds: []
    10cee608-9eec-488a-8b24-b541623d0fe1:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 730
        'y': 660
      z: 1
      embeds: []
    f0410b0f-a2df-48b6-9788-39a256d08eae:
      size:
        width: 150
        height: 150
      position:
        x: 60
        'y': 660
      z: 1
      embeds: []
    702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd:
      size:
        width: 240
        height: 240
      position:
        x: 570
        'y': 120
      z: 1
      embeds:
        - 9b07d92a-36f9-4ca7-b4f9-40753f1378b0
        - 58ad94a5-9d1f-4e1f-ae00-b9069c760c77
    a3c175b4-faf1-4eac-9242-941a6a932a70:
      size:
        width: 150
        height: 150
      position:
        x: 660
        'y': 90
      z: 1
      embeds: []
    db29192c-fd22-4c87-94b1-d1e41208d236:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 770
        'y': 540
      z: 1
      embeds: []
    925feb40-cd97-4e4e-b56f-87b10aabc2ab:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 320
        'y': 620
      z: 1
      embeds: []
    608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff:
      size:
        width: 240
        height: 240
      position:
        x: 880
        'y': 510
      z: 1
      embeds:
        - 05eb18d9-0497-41c1-8c12-edf0a9caed16
    7e0c544e-910b-4641-a19c-68ee82898135:
      source:
        id: f0410b0f-a2df-48b6-9788-39a256d08eae
      target:
        id: 10cee608-9eec-488a-8b24-b541623d0fe1
      z: 1
    05eb18d9-0497-41c1-8c12-edf0a9caed16:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 910
        'y': 570
      z: 2
      parent: 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
      embeds: []
      isassociatedwith:
        - 10cee608-9eec-488a-8b24-b541623d0fe1
      iscontainedinside:
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
        - 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
      dependson:
        - 7e0c544e-910b-4641-a19c-68ee82898135
    e0179fd8-f057-4e90-8a5f-a446819a41d4:
      size:
        width: 150
        height: 150
      position:
        x: 480
        'y': 390
      z: 1
      embeds: []
    5f524e69-2fcb-4c51-a191-e6c5f3df3e34:
      size:
        width: 150
        height: 150
      position:
        x: 210
        'y': 390
      z: 1
      embeds: []
    52a67d2e-df44-4440-b3ef-4afe0984de88:
      source:
        id: a3c175b4-faf1-4eac-9242-941a6a932a70
      target:
        id: 5f524e69-2fcb-4c51-a191-e6c5f3df3e34
      z: 1
    3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6:
      size:
        width: 240
        height: 240
      position:
        x: 300
        'y': 60
      z: 1
      embeds:
        - c1ff09b0-2e8e-4521-8154-3b94b5a600f8
    ae8384a4-37c1-4865-8b97-2745a3a8b3e1:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 510
        'y': 660
      z: 1
      embeds: []
    58ad94a5-9d1f-4e1f-ae00-b9069c760c77:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 600
        'y': 180
      z: 2
      parent: 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
      embeds: []
      isassociatedwith:
        - ae8384a4-37c1-4865-8b97-2745a3a8b3e1
      iscontainedinside:
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
        - 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
    04996b8c-bca2-4427-84e1-a7a83896a064:
      source:
        id: a3c175b4-faf1-4eac-9242-941a6a932a70
      target:
        id: 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
      z: 1
    abf07dea-ed6c-4cf6-9a5b-f0f9c7c2a786:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 970
        'y': 100
      z: 1
      embeds: []
    ce9c0357-7785-4df9-8a35-90a70b25503c:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 840
        'y': 210
      z: 1
      embeds: []
    d34ee484-081e-4e35-9cf3-3b17666df818:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 840
        'y': 330
      z: 1
      embeds: []
      iscontainedinside:
        - f0410b0f-a2df-48b6-9788-39a256d08eae
    e5ce1987-9fc2-4413-9f04-eeacb78bdffc:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 1050
        'y': 270
      z: 1
      embeds: []
    84837bdc-620c-4ff2-8efb-2bf7173a7096:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 920
        'y': 410
      z: 1
      embeds: []
      isassociatedwith:
        - e5ce1987-9fc2-4413-9f04-eeacb78bdffc
        - 4b12ea4b-e211-4f55-a823-4da7113ce154
      iscontainedinside:
        - e0179fd8-f057-4e90-8a5f-a446819a41d4
      dependson:
        - f0410b0f-a2df-48b6-9788-39a256d08eae
    c1ff09b0-2e8e-4521-8154-3b94b5a600f8:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 330
        'y': 120
      z: 2
      parent: 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
      embeds: []
      iscontainedinside:
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
    44f9157c-7abe-48e1-b19a-9b5066a87acb:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: -20
        'y': 170
      z: 0
      embeds: []
    421548e4-192c-4a89-b236-41eb956dc7f3:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 180
        'y': 230
      z: 0
      embeds: []
      isassociatedwith:
        - d34ee484-081e-4e35-9cf3-3b17666df818
      iscontainedinside:
        - 5f524e69-2fcb-4c51-a191-e6c5f3df3e34
        - 5f524e69-2fcb-4c51-a191-e6c5f3df3e34
        - e0179fd8-f057-4e90-8a5f-a446819a41d4
        - 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
    3517f34b-2be3-49d1-a3b6-8db672475be2:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 30
        'y': 430
      z: 0
      embeds: []
      iscontainedinside:
        - f0410b0f-a2df-48b6-9788-39a256d08eae
      dependson:
        - d0c17083-9c13-48c2-8e13-948b2a096e71
    d0c17083-9c13-48c2-8e13-948b2a096e71:
      size:
        width: 60
        height: 60
      position:
        x: 30
        'y': 300
      z: 0
      embeds: []
Description: 'entire VPC and EC2,ELB config'
Parameters:
  InstanceType:
    Description: WebServer EC2 instance type
    Type: String
    Default: t2.micro
    AllowedValues:
      - t1.micro
      - t2.nano
      - t2.micro
      - t2.small
      - t2.medium
      - t2.large
      - m1.small
      - m1.medium
      - m1.large
      - m1.xlarge
      - m2.xlarge
      - m2.2xlarge
      - m2.4xlarge
      - m3.medium
      - m3.large
      - m3.xlarge
      - m3.2xlarge
      - m4.large
      - m4.xlarge
      - m4.2xlarge
      - m4.4xlarge
      - m4.10xlarge
      - c1.medium
      - c1.xlarge
      - c3.large
      - c3.xlarge
      - c3.2xlarge
      - c3.4xlarge
      - c3.8xlarge
      - c4.large
      - c4.xlarge
      - c4.2xlarge
      - c4.4xlarge
      - c4.8xlarge
      - g2.2xlarge
      - g2.8xlarge
      - r3.large
      - r3.xlarge
      - r3.2xlarge
      - r3.4xlarge
      - r3.8xlarge
      - i2.xlarge
      - i2.2xlarge
      - i2.4xlarge
      - i2.8xlarge
      - d2.xlarge
      - d2.2xlarge
      - d2.4xlarge
      - d2.8xlarge
      - hi1.4xlarge
      - hs1.8xlarge
      - cr1.8xlarge
      - cc2.8xlarge
      - cg1.4xlarge
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid EC2 instance type.
  KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instances
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName'
    ConstraintDescription: must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.
  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: '(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})'
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.
  VPCName:
    Description: The name of the VPC being created.
    Type: String
    Default: VPC Public and Private with NAT
Mappings:
  ##removed for char limit(used wordpress ami##
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
    Properties:
      EnableDnsSupport: 'true'
      EnableDnsHostnames: 'true'
      CidrBlock: !FindInMap 
        - SubnetConfig
        - VPC
        - CIDR
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        - Key: Network
          Value: Public
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref VPCName
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: f0410b0f-a2df-48b6-9788-39a256d08eae
  PublicSubnet0:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1b
      CidrBlock: !FindInMap 
        - SubnetConfig
        - Public0
        - CIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: 'true'
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        - Key: Network
          Value: Public
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join 
            - ''
            - - !Ref VPCName
              - '-public-'
              - !Select 
                - 0
                - !FindInMap 
                  - AZRegions
                  - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
                  - AZs
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 3f2064e8-d473-4556-b09f-952c8da429e6
  PublicSubnet1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1b
      CidrBlock: !FindInMap 
        - SubnetConfig
        - Public1
        - CIDR
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: 'true'
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        - Key: Network
          Value: Public
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join 
            - ''
            - - !Ref VPCName
              - '-public-'
              - !Select 
                - 1
                - !FindInMap 
                  - AZRegions
                  - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
                  - AZs
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 5f524e69-2fcb-4c51-a191-e6c5f3df3e34
  PrivateSubnet0:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
      CidrBlock: !FindInMap 
        - SubnetConfig
        - Private0
        - CIDR
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        - Key: Network
          Value: Private
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join 
            - ''
            - - !Ref VPCName
              - '-private-'
              - !Select 
                - 0
                - !FindInMap 
                  - AZRegions
                  - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
                  - AZs
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: e0179fd8-f057-4e90-8a5f-a446819a41d4
  InternetGateway:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::InternetGateway'
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        - Key: Network
          Value: Public
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join 
            - ''
            - - !Ref VPCName
              - '-IGW'
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 10cee608-9eec-488a-8b24-b541623d0fe1
  GatewayToInternet:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 7e0c544e-910b-4641-a19c-68ee82898135
  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        - Key: Network
          Value: Public
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join 
            - ''
            - - !Ref VPCName
              - '-public-route-table'
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 608b0bd0-06e9-4c6a-91f3-129e176fa8ff
  PublicRoute:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    DependsOn: GatewayToInternet
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 05eb18d9-0497-41c1-8c12-edf0a9caed16
  PublicSubnetRouteTableAssociation0:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet0
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
  PublicSubnetRouteTableAssociation1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
  PublicNetworkAcl:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        - Key: Network
          Value: Public
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join 
            - ''
            - - !Ref VPCName
              - '-public-nacl'
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: a3c175b4-faf1-4eac-9242-941a6a932a70
  InboundHTTPPublicNetworkAclEntry:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref PublicNetworkAcl
      RuleNumber: '100'
      Protocol: '-1'
      RuleAction: allow
      Egress: 'false'
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      PortRange:
        From: '0'
        To: '65535'
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 925feb40-cd97-4e4e-b56f-87b10aabc2ab
  OutboundPublicNetworkAclEntry:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref PublicNetworkAcl
      RuleNumber: '100'
      Protocol: '-1'
      RuleAction: allow
      Egress: 'true'
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      PortRange:
        From: '0'
        To: '65535'
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: db29192c-fd22-4c87-94b1-d1e41208d236
  PublicSubnetNetworkAclAssociation0:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet0
      NetworkAclId: !Ref PublicNetworkAcl
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 04996b8c-bca2-4427-84e1-a7a83896a064
  PublicSubnetNetworkAclAssociation1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1
      NetworkAclId: !Ref PublicNetworkAcl
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 52a67d2e-df44-4440-b3ef-4afe0984de88
  ElasticIP0:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIP'
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 9b07d92a-36f9-4ca7-b4f9-40753f1378b0
  NATGateway0:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NatGateway'
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt 
        - ElasticIP0
        - AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet0
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: ae8384a4-37c1-4865-8b97-2745a3a8b3e1
  PrivateRouteTable0:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join 
            - ''
            - - !Ref VPCName
              - '-private-route-table-0'
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 702fe9ac-3a89-4063-a715-aaea1b5400fd
  PrivateRouteToInternet0:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable0
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NATGateway0
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 58ad94a5-9d1f-4e1f-ae00-b9069c760c77
  PrivateSubnetRouteTableAssociation0:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet0
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable0
  WebServerGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup'
    Properties:
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet0
      AvailabilityZones:
        - us-east-1a
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref LaunchConfig
      MinSize: '2'
      MaxSize: '4'
      LoadBalancerNames:
        - !Ref StackALB
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 84837bdc-620c-4ff2-8efb-2bf7173a7096
    DependsOn:
      - VPC
  LaunchConfig:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration'
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Init':
        verify_instance_health:
          commands:
            ELBHealthCheck:
              command: !Sub >-
                until [ "$state" == "\"InService\"" ]; do state=$(aws --region
                ${AWS::Region} elb describe-instance-health --load-balancer-name
                ${StackALB} --instances $(curl -s
                http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) --query
                InstanceStates[0].State); sleep 10; done
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: e5ce1987-9fc2-4413-9f04-eeacb78bdffc
    Properties:
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      ImageId: !FindInMap 
        - AWSRegionArch2AMI
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - !FindInMap 
          - AWSInstanceType2Arch
          - !Ref InstanceType
          - Arch
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref WebServerInstanceProfile
  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH access and HTTP access on the configured port
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: !Ref SSHLocation
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: d34ee484-081e-4e35-9cf3-3b17666df818
  WebServerInstanceProfile:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile'
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - !Ref DescribeHealthRole
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: ce9c0357-7785-4df9-8a35-90a70b25503c
  DescribeHealthRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: describe-instance-health-policy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'elasticloadbalancing:DescribeInstanceHealth'
                  - 'elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets'
                  - 'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets'
                  - 'elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer'
                  - 'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer'
                  - 'ec2:Describe*'
                  - 'ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress'
                Resource: '*'
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: abf07dea-ed6c-4cf6-9a5b-f0f9c7c2a786
  Bastionins:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-052efd3df9dad4825
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - AssociatePublicIpAddress: 'true'
          DeviceIndex: '0'
          GroupSet:
            - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
          SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet0
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: c1ff09b0-2e8e-4521-8154-3b94b5a600f8
  R53HC46WDD:
    Type: 'AWS::Route53::HealthCheck'
    Properties:
      HealthCheckConfig:
        Type: HTTP
        FullyQualifiedDomainName: !GetAtt 
          - StackALB
          - DNSName
        RequestInterval: '30'
        FailureThreshold: '5'
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 44f9157c-7abe-48e1-b19a-9b5066a87acb
  StackALB:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer'
    Properties:
      Name: StackALB
      Scheme: internet-facing
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
      Subnets:
        - !Ref PublicSubnet0
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet0
      Type: application
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 421548e4-192c-4a89-b236-41eb956dc7f3
  TargetGroup1:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup'
    Properties:
      TargetType: alb
      Targets:
        - Id: !Ref StackALB
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: 3517f34b-2be3-49d1-a3b6-8db672475be2
  ALBlistener:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener'
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          ForwardConfig:
            TargetGroups:
              - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup1
                Weight: 1
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref StackALB
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: d0c17083-9c13-48c2-8e13-948b2a096e71
```

Comment: Just letting yall know i was braindead, i misunderstood what the field meant. i wanted to target it to ```instance```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`alb` `TargetType` is only [supported for NLB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#target-type), [not ALB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#target-type). So you have to change your setup to use NLB if you want to use `alb` as target in your target group.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/create-application-load-balancer.html

`If your service's task definition uses the awsvpc network mode (which is required for the Fargate launch type), you must choose IP addresses as the target type This is because tasks that use the awsvpc network mode are associated with an elastic network interface, not an Amazon EC2 instance.`